# Undefined reference to `clock_gettime', modify makefile?

Tags: linux, installation, ipopt

I know that this question has been asked elsewhere, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17128773/undefined-reference-to-clock-gettime-in-linux-using-icc), but I could not find the solution to my specific problem in there.

I have been trying to install the software [Ipopt](https://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt) on Linux, followed the instructions in the documentation, but when I run make I obtain the following error:

```
/obs/xxx/Ipopt-3.12.8/build/ThirdParty/ASL/.libs/libcoinasl.so: undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [ipopt] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/xxx_home/xxx/Ipopt-3.12.8/build/Ipopt/src/Apps/AmplSolver'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/xxx_home/xxx/Ipopt-3.12.8/build/Ipopt/src/Apps'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/xxx_home/xxx/Ipopt-3.12.8/build/Ipopt'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

According to the posts above, the way around this is to include the -lrt flag, but I do not know whether I should insert it in the make file, in what makefile, and where exactly in the makefile. FYI, here is the [Ipopt archive](https://www.coin-or.org/download/source/Ipopt/Ipopt-3.12.8.tgz) that I have been using, where you can find the Makefile, and here is some information about my linux distribution

```
$ uname -or
3.2.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 GNU/Linux
$ lsb_release -irc
Distributor ID: Debian
Release:    6.0.10
Codename:   squeeze
```

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ error: undefined reference to 'clock\_gettime' and 'clock\_settime'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2418157/608639) and [GCC with -std=c99 complains about not knowing struct timespec](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3875197/608639), [Append compile flags to CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS while configuration/make](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23407635/608639), [Where to add a CFLAG, such as -std=gnu99, into an autotools project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11647208/608639), etc. Your compile command may need `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ipopt i see is configured with [configure script](https://github.com/coin-or/Ipopt/blob/master/configure), reading [help from that script](https://github.com/coin-or/Ipopt/blob/master/configure) i guess you can just ADD_CFLAGS compiler flags:

```
ADD_CFLAGS=-lrt ./configure
```

and then run make.

Comment: That works, thank you.